# How to get calendar notifications when my phone is on silent

Tags: iphone

I am frequently missing meetings because my company moved over to gsuite and the meeting invites are silent notifications on my computer.

I want my calendar notifications to cause my phone to make noises but I want text, phone calls, and everything else to remain silent so that my phone isn’t going off the wall during meetings all day.

Is there a way to make calendar notifications the only thing that isn’t silent?  Is there an Apple Watch app that can do this for me?

Answer (score 2):

You can manually set all non-calendar sounds to "None" or "Vibrate only", from iOS Settings --> Sounds & Haptics

This has consequence outside of work hours, though.  You may be able to work around that with a Siri Shortcut, if that becomes a problem for you.